# bootstrap как сделать отступ между блоками

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте. [Сайт](http://mebel-v-orle.ru/home/index) сверстан на bootstrap.
На `lg` экранах смотрится прекрасно, с отступом между картинками. На мониторах типа md смотрится отвратно - сливаются блоки без отступов. [Вот тут можно проверить](http://ami.responsivedesign.is/#).

```
@model Site.Models.MebelModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Title;
}

@if (Model.Id!=0)
{
    <ul class="breadcrumb" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <li><a href="/home/index" style="color:#ff6a00;">Вся мебель</a> <span class="divider"></span></li>

        @if (Model.Level>=2)
        {
            <li><a href="/home/index?id=@Model.ParentId" style="color:#ff6a00;">@Model.Name</a> <span class="divider"></span></li>
        }
        <li class="active">@ViewBag.Title</li>
    </ul>

}

<div class="col-md-1">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    @if (Model.Id != 0)
    {
        <h2 class="zagolovok">@ViewBag.Title</h2>
    }
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.CatalogList)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="margin-left: 8.333333333333332%;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="view view-tenth">
                                <img class="img-thumbnail" style=" box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 0px #909090;" src="../Content/Images/@item.SmallImage" />
                                <div class="mask">
                                    <h2>@item.Caption</h2>
                                    <p>@item.UnderLine</p>
                                    <a href="/@item.Controller/@item.Metod?id=@item.Id" class="info">Смотреть</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p style="margin-top:15px;text-align:center;"><a class="index-link" href="/@item.Controller/@item.Metod?id=@item.Id">@item.Title</a></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо bootstrap лучше было изучить. нужно для отступов использовать класс offset с соответствующими col_md (в случае для верстки под ноутбуки). А так же правильно выбирать контейнер.